# Azure notification hub installation c#

Tags: ios, azure-notificationhub

Can anyone help me with Azure notification hub, how to set up device installation form c# code. I have problem with the Installation object. How to set it to pass it as parameter to CreateOrUpdateInstallation method of hub client instance. It's not clear to me.

I have a hub on azure that works with device registration like charm in local, but uploaded on azure are not working. Now I wanna try with istalation.

thnx

update: after 4 days, I figured out, that you can't send notification to yourself. Azure somehow knows that you are sending notification to yours phone, and that's why my welcome message never delivered to my phone.

update: this is how now I install the device i my backend code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/push/test-installation")]
public async Task<IActionResult> NotificationInstalationTest()
{
 string connectionString = "{{my connection string}}";
 string hubName = "{{my hub name}}";
 string token = "{{tokne}}";

 NotificationHubClient hubClient = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(connectionString, hubName);

 string notificationText = $"Test message for Azure delivery for Atila at: {DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()}";

 var alert = new JObject
 (
      new JProperty("aps", new JObject(new JProperty("alert", notificationText))),
      new JProperty("inAppMessage", notificationText)
 ).ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);

 IList<string> tags = new List<string>();
 tags.Add("email");

 IDictionary<string, string> pushVariables = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 pushVariables.Add( "email", "atila@panonicit.com" );

 Installation installation = new Installation();
 installation.InstallationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
 installation.Platform = NotificationPlatform.Apns;
 installation.PushChannel = token;
 installation.Tags = tags;
 installation.PushVariables = pushVariables;

 await hubClient.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation);
 NotificationOutcome result = await hubClient.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(alert);

 return Ok("Success");
}
```

Now when I hit this endpoint with Postman it works, if the same endpoint call comes from iOS it not works!

thnx

Answer (score 0):

> How to set it to pass it as parameter to CreateOrUpdateInstallation method of hub client instance. It's not clear to me.

Based on my understanding, you are registering the notification hub from your backend using the installation model. For your WebAPI project, assuming your method for create/update an installation as follows:

**InstallationController.cs**

```html
//PUT api/installation
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Put(DeviceInstallation deviceUpdate)
{
    Installation installation = new Installation();
    installation.InstallationId = deviceUpdate.InstallationId;
    //TODO:
    await hub.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

For your mobile client, you could refer to the following method:

```html
private async Task<HttpStatusCode> CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(DeviceInstallation deviceInstallation)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        //TODO: set your authorization header
        //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization

        var putUri =$"{your-backend-endpoint}/api/installation";
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deviceInstallation);
        var response = await httpClient.PutAsync(putUri, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        return response.StatusCode;
    }
}
```

Moreover, for more details you could refer to [Registration management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification#register-for-notifications-by-using-the-webapi-back-end) for building backend with the registration model to build your backend using the installation model.

Comment: thnx for the answer. Yes I am trying to install device through backend, because registration not works, it simple not delivers messages when I upload to Azure. Device installation works on Azure, only when I hit the controller with Postman. Any idea?

Comment: Any exceptions when calling the endpoint from your IOS? You could try to follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer) for troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: No exceptions, nothing. That's the problem. It's like a black box, we can't see why it is not pushed when call comes from the device.

Comment: Have you tried to send the notification via the Test Send blade on azure portal? Also, please try to check the metrics for your notification hub under the "MONITORING > Metrics" about the APNS related metrics to narrow this issue.

Comment: Yes I tried, and it delivers. It delivers from VS2015 too. It's only not received when user login with the phone. For test we added a welcome message for the first login, when the device is registered, and if I hit the controller with postman withe the corresponding model, it works, it the model comes from phone it not works. Here is where I posted my question with lots of code snippets:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778371/azure-app-service-not-delivers-push-notification